# I want to add a linear gradient of variable top and bottom width

Tags: css, linear-gradients

So i want to apply linear gradient to a picture such that, it ends at 75% width at the top and 35% bottom. I have looked around but seem to have no luck so far

[image: This is the image]

Comment: @Mgkrish it's possible :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with 2 linear-gradient as follow.

The first gradient will fill until 35% of the width with a rectangular shape, then the second will start when the first one ends with a width of 40% and a triangle shape, so you will have 35%+40% = 75% on the top and we keep 35% at the bottom:

[image]

```css
.box {
  height:300px;
  background:
  linear-gradient(to bottom right,rgba(0,180,0,0.7) 50%,transparent 50.5%) calc(35% / 0.6) 0/40% 100% no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(to right,rgba(0,180,0,0.7),rgba(0,180,0,0.7)) 0 0/35.05% 100% no-repeat,
  url(https://lorempixel.com/1000/1000/) center/cover no-repeat
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Almost all the values used are pretty easy to understand. The first gradient is positioned at `[0,0]` with a width of `35%` and a height `100%`. For the second one, the height/width are clear but the position is a bit tricky, so I will explain it.

First we need to understand how percentage values works with `background-position`. You may take a look at [this link](https://css-tricks.com/i-like-how-percentage-background-position-works/) for more information and some illustration. Considering this, here is a graphic to show the value we need to calculate of `background-position-x` (that I will call **p**)

[image]

Considering how the background position is calculated we know that `p` define the percentage **outside**, `x` define the percentage **inside** and both are equal. From this we can have the relation between `x` and `p` whic is `(x/40) = (p/100)` ~ `x = 0.4*p`. We can also clearly see that `p - x` is equal to the width of the first gradient which is 35% so we have:

`p - x = 35%` => `p - 0.4*p = 35%` => `0.6*p = 35%` => `p=35%/0.6`

Comment: Interesting...you might want to explain how this works...and why

Comment: Nice... *sneaky* too!

Comment: @Paulie_D i added more explanation ;) but still a small issue with the position of the second one, not accurate

Comment: @UdimManasseh what did you not understand in the code ? as i wrote a detailed explanation with graphics :)

Comment: Had network issues, so my page didn't reload. I have seen the explanation.